# Мне нужно чтобы в моём коде отсортированые слова выходили в список без повторений, и чтобы выдавалось количество каждой буквы в строке

Tags: python

```
    vvid = bool(int(input("1 если сортировать , 2 если считать: ")))
    if vvid  == 1:
        text=str(input("Enter text: "))
        w=text.split()
        e=""
        for r in sorted(w):
            e=e+" " +r
    print(e);
```

Comment: вопрос еще раз перечитайте :) - если со словами более-менее понятно, то какие буквы в строке то? в какой строке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vvid = bool(int(input("1 если сортировать , 2 если считать: ")))
if vvid  == 1:
```

вот этот код у вас будет работать всегда, если пользователь вводит 1 или 2, то при переводе в `bool` всё будет `True`, а проверка `True == 1` будет срабатывать всегда :)

теперь касательно сортировки слов, то можно слова занести в множество (оно может содержать только уникальные элементы), потом преобразовать множество в список и отсортировать:

```
text = "text data text"
data = sorted(list(set(text.split())))
print(data) # будет выведено ['data', 'text']
```

чтобы подсчитать кол-во букв в строке можно использовать словарь:

```
text = "text data text"
data = dict()

for letter in text:
    data[letter] = data.get(letter, 0) + 1

print(data) # будет выведено {'t': 5, 'e': 2, 'x': 2, ' ': 2, 'd': 1, 'a': 2}
```